# Detecting Patterns in dataset using clustering algorithm

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have a dataset that contains a cross pattern. How can I filter off this cross-like pattern?

Tried DBScan but it didn't work effectively. Also, can't use any cluster which needs to specify number of clusters as the data cleaning needs to be automated.

[image: data pattern]

Comment: Try PCA and SVM analysis on your dataset.

Comment: @ASH, could you please tell more about SVM? how SVM can help to detect? I tried PCA, does not help either.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, forget SVM, that's for classification. Honestly, I didn't ready your question carefully the first time. I just re-read what you posted originally. Try Mean Shift for automatically detecting the optimal number of clusters. Here's an example. Hopefully you can adapt it for your specific use.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

# #############################################################################
# Generate sample data
centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1], [1, -1], [1, -1]]
X, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=10000, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.2)

# #############################################################################
# Compute clustering with MeanShift

# The following bandwidth can be automatically detected using
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(X, quantile=0.6, n_samples=5000)

ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)
ms.fit(X)
labels = ms.labels_
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_

labels_unique = np.unique(labels)
n_clusters_ = len(labels_unique)

print("number of estimated clusters : %d" % n_clusters_)

# #############################################################################
# Plot result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()

colors = cycle('bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk')
for k, col in zip(range(n_clusters_), colors):
    my_members = labels == k
    cluster_center = cluster_centers[k]
    plt.plot(X[my_members, 0], X[my_members, 1], col + '.')
    plt.plot(cluster_center[0], cluster_center[1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)
plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, try this.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
  
# We will be using the make_blobs method 
# in order to generate our own data. 
  
clusters = [[2, 2, 2], [7, 7, 7], [5, 13, 13]] 
  
X, _ = make_blobs(n_samples = 150, centers = clusters, 
                                   cluster_std = 0.60) 
   
# After training the model, We store the 
# coordinates for the cluster centers 
ms = MeanShift() 
ms.fit(X) 
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_ 
   
# Finally We plot the data points 
# and centroids in a 3D graph. 
fig = plt.figure() 
  
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection ='3d') 
  
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2], marker ='o') 
  
ax.scatter(cluster_centers[:, 0], cluster_centers[:, 1], 
           cluster_centers[:, 2], marker ='x', color ='red', 
           s = 300, linewidth = 5, zorder = 10) 
  
plt.show()
```

[image]

There are a few clustering methodologies that help you choose the optimal number of clusters automatically. Check out the link below for some ideas of how to move forward with your project.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html